# How to load a library .so file into android application?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

Can anyone tell me with an .so file given we need to calla `jni` method in app? The .so file contains implementation methods in `C`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not so trivial question ... I get answer in 10 days ! You can try to do something or to start doing something and if you have questions I will always ready to help !

Comment: Thanks for ur respose .i want to use a .so file which is given by client and call the methods in that .so file.

Comment: hey @rajeswari did you find any way to use the .so file and call the methods in that. I am trying to used a .so file to call native methods but getting Exception of no implementation found.

Comment: @rajeswari did you got a answer for question i am facing also the same difficulty.

Answer (score 4):

use this code..

```
 public class NativeLib {

      static {
        System.loadLibrary("ndk_demo");
      }

      /** 
       * Adds two integers, returning their sum
       */
      public native int add( int v1, int v2 );

      /**
       * Returns Hello World string
       */
      public native String hello();
    }
```

for more info..http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

Comment: Thanks for ur respose but i want to use a .so file which is given by client and call the methods in that .so file.

Comment: link is not available now

Comment: @Sujit this solution gives me UnsatisfiedLink error