# Can`t run on Android device, because of librabries

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, shared-libraries

I'm launching a game on Android device and getting this error. I`m using up to date Android version, also libgdx.

> The library 'jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
>   
> The following libraries were found:
>   
> libjinput-linux.so
>   
> libjinput-linux64.so

Please help me understand what may cause the problem.

Comment: Where do you see that JInput supports Android?

Comment: I haven` t seen, I don` t know how it get there, could you please help me out? How can I get rid of it? @CommonsWare

Comment: "How can I get rid of it?" -- well, something in your project is trying to use this library. Did you add this JAR yourself? If so, why? If not, where is it coming from within your workspace?

Comment: @CommonsWare I haven` t added by myself, and I think it can`t be coming from my workscape, because I`ve created a new one just for this project. How can I help you to help me? Maybe some screenshots would help?

Comment: By "coming from within your workspace", I meant any Android library projects that you may have imported and attached to your application project. I mean, that JAR has to be *somewhere*, otherwise Eclipse couldn't be complaining about it. Where is it?

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thanks for your time, and I`m sorry, but I don`t know how I can find it, if only you could tell me how to search for it, I`ll find it! Tryed to search for it in my project libraries, also on my workspace...

Comment: "I dont know how I can find it" -- it should be on your hard drive somewhere. Search it via your development operating system (e.g., **`find`** command on OS X or Linux).

Comment: @CommonsWare Found it, it`s in :

C:\Users\Vaclovas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\7ff832a6eb9ab6a767f1ade2b548092d0fa64795



What I do with this file?

Comment: OK, so you are using Gradle for your builds. I assumed otherwise, since this is tagged `eclipse`. You can use the [Gradle dependency report](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_dependencies) to try to track down what artifact is trying to use that JAR. Whatever it is, it would not appear to be compatible with Android.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file from your project?

Comment: It looks like you've managed to get your desktop dependencies mixed up in your Android project. Check the android and core dependencies and make sure neither references lwjgl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*.so files are native assemblies that are built for a particular architecture. If those *.so files were not built for android (and it seems as if they are not given the error) they will not work.

If there isn't a version for android already built, you can try to write an android version. [This other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453404/how-to-load-a-library-so-file-into-android-application) may be of assistance.